# Eclipse: how to disable XML validation for a specific test-file?

Tags: xml, eclipse

Im my projects .../src/test/resources/xml directory there is an XML file called invalid.xml which - as the name might suggest - contains non-valid XML. This file is used in one of our test cases to - well, you might guess - test how the program behaves if we feed it with an invalid XML file.

Now, the issue is that Eclipse validates all these XML files during build and - since that file doesn't properly validate - displays an error and stops the build. How can I exclude this specific file (or if not possible: the entire folder) from being validated during builds?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Validation:
1. Click Window > Preferences and select Validation in the left pane. The Validation page of the Preferences window lists the validators available in your project and their settings.

2. To disable individual validators, clear the check boxes next to each validator that you want to disable. Each validator has a check box to specify whether it is enabled for manual validation or on a build.

3. Optional: You can also change the following check box options on this page:

[image]4. Click OK.

Source: Eclipse Documentation

Comment: There's also a way to disable it for individual files: https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/rtunevalidat.html?cp=96_1_0_6_0

Comment: @work service I am aware of that but I wouldn't want to disable validation for ALL .xml files.

Comment: @nitind this goes exactly in the direction I wanted to see! I tried it and it seems to fit my bill. Thanks!  Feel free to convert this comment into an answer and I will accept it.